Is this interpretation of change-of-basis on an input and output basis correct?
I had already written another post here How is the matrix of a transformation represented when performing change of basis on both the input and output basis? so I suppose this is a continuation of the questions I had.
Let $T$ be a linear transformation 
Let $V_1$ be an input basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ 
Let $W_1$ be an output basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$ 
Let $A$ be a representative matrix of $T$ between bases $V_1$ and $W_1$ 
Let $V_2$ be an input basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ 
Let $W_2$ be an output basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$ 
Let $B$ be a representative matrix of $T$ between bases $V_2$ and $W_2$ 
Let $M_1$ be the change-of-basis matrix from $V_1$ to $V_2$ 
Let $M_2$ be the change-of-basis matrix from $W_1$ to $W_2$ 
Let $v_1$ be a vector formed by the input basis $V_1$ 
Let $v_2$ be a vector formed by the input basis $V_2$
I think my question boils down to how do we interpret the change-of-basis of a matrix associated with a transformation? Generally speaking, I understand that when we refer to the change-of-basis, we typically mean consider some basis $V$ and some basis $W$, then the change-of-basis matrix, say $M$, gives us a schematic for converting coordinates from $V$ to coordinates in $W$, which consequently forms a bijection between vectors of both bases, i.e., $V \leftrightarrow W$ .
I guess, to dive further into my question, does it make sense to refer to some change-of-basis between matrices? For example, let $A$ be a representative matrix of $T$ in regards to input and output bases $V_1$ and $W_1$. Then, suppose we perform a change-of-basis from $V_1$ to $V_2$ represented by $M_1$ and from $W_1$ to $W_2$ represented by $M_2$. Would the the change-of-basis of $A$ then be $B = M_2AM_1$ or $B = M_2AM^{-1}$, or would it be something like $C = M_2^{-1}BM_1$. If so, is this $B$ the same $B$ that represents $T$ but in regards to the different input and output bases of $V_2$ and $W_2$? If we perform change-of-basis on both the input and output basis of $A$, is the matrix of the transformation now automatically represented by $B$, i.e., $B$ already existed as a representative matrix of $T$ that linked $V_2$ to $W_2$? To illustrate how I'm thinking about the process:
$$\begin{matrix}
V_1 & \rightarrow & A(v_1) & \rightarrow & W_1 \newline
\downarrow_{M_1} & & & & \downarrow_{M_2} \newline
V_2 & \rightarrow & B(v_2) & \rightarrow & W_2
\end{matrix}$$
In regards to this  where it says "the new matrix is $M^{-1}AM$", I'm not really sure how that's the case.
If $M_1$ is the change-of-basis matrix between $V_1$ and $V_2$, then doesn't $M_1v$ give us a vector of $V_2$? Then $M_1^{-1}$ takes some coordinates and gives us back a vector in $V_1$. I thought the transformation we're applying needs to be on vectors of the same basis? So, it doesn't seem like $A$ could be applied to $M_1v$ since it's a vector of $V_2$ and even though $v$ exists within the same input space $\mathbb{R}^n$, when they're contextualized within their respective bases $V_1$ and $V_2$, they don't produce the same vector. or does it not matter since $V_1$ and $V_2$ both being a basis for the input space $\mathbb{R}^n$ means they span the input space and thus we can apply $A$ to it regardless such that $M_2^{-1}AM_1$ still maps appropriately between contexts. Furthermore, would the matrix $A$ in $M_1^{-1}AM_1$ have to be a matrix that actually maps from $V_2$ to $W_2$, i.e, that matrix is actually $B$?
It's my understanding that if we consider the change-of-basis matrix between $V_1$ and $V_2$, then $AM_1$ represents the matrix such that $AM_1v$ of $V_2$. Then, does $C = M_1^{-1}AM_1$ represents the change-of-basis of $A$ but for $V_2$ and $W_2$?. In the case the input basis $V_1$ is equal to the output basis $W_1$ and we perform the same change of basis on both $V_1$ and $W_1$, then $M_1$ = $M_2$. Then, could it be said that the representation of A in another basis is $C = M_2^{-1}AM_1 = M_1^{-1}AM_1$? I wasn't sure if this how the $M_1^{-1}AM_1$ is arrived to by the author.

I see where I blundered. The answer was right in this diagram the entire time I was just messing it up.
I see that generally the change-of-basis for some matrix $A$ representing some linear transformation $T$, wherein we perform change-of-basis on input basis and output basis, i.e., from $V_1$ to $V_2$ and from $W_1$ to $W_2$ is represented like this:
$$\begin{matrix}
V_1 & \rightarrow & A(v_1) & \rightarrow & W_1 \newline
\downarrow_{M_1} & & & & \downarrow_{M_2} \newline
V_2 & \rightarrow & B(v_2) & \rightarrow & W_2
\end{matrix}$$
Thus, since we want A to only act on vectors contextualized within its input basis, what we actually want to do is take vectors from B, contextualize them with the input basis of A, morph them by A, and then take the resulting vectors back to the output basis of B. Thus, the diagram for the change-of-basis matrix for A to a different input and output basis (which I believe inherently admits B assuming they are of the same change on both the input and output basis?) would be like:
$$\begin{matrix}
V_1 & \rightarrow & A(v_1) & \rightarrow & W_1 \newline
\uparrow_{M_1^{-1}} & & & & \downarrow_{M_2} \newline
V_2 & \rightarrow & B(v_2) & \rightarrow & W_2
\end{matrix}$$
Then, the change-of-basis matrix is represented by $B = M_2AM_1^{-1}$.
However, if I had instead had the original diagram drawn like so:
$$\begin{matrix}
V_1 & \rightarrow & A(v_1) & \rightarrow & W_1 \newline
\uparrow_{M_1} & & & & \uparrow_{M_2} \newline
V_2 & \rightarrow & B(v_2) & \rightarrow & W_2
\end{matrix}$$
Then, the change-of-basis matrix is $B = M_2^{-1}AM_1$. Furthermore, if we had the input basis of A equal the output basis of A, i.e., $V_1 = W_1$ and we performed the same change-of-basis on both $V_1$ and $W_1$, then $M_1 = M_2$ and we would end up with the diagram
$$\begin{matrix}
V_1 & \rightarrow & A(v_1) & \rightarrow & W_1 \newline
\uparrow_{M_1} & & & & \uparrow_{M_2 = M_1} \newline
V_2 & \rightarrow & B(v_2) & \rightarrow & W_2
\end{matrix}$$
Thus, the change-of-basis matrix would be $B = M_1^{-1}AM_1$ and we also see that $A = M_1^{-1}BM_1$ which gives us the common notation of matrix similarity. So, it looks like the change-of-basis of a matrix A yields a similar matrix B that represents the same linear transformation.
